# Powering AT90USB162 microcontroller from USB

Tags: power-supply, usb, avr

I have a new AT90USB162 [(docs)](https://eu.mouser.com/datasheet/2/268/doc7707-1369075.pdf). I would like to use my USB 2.0 socket and USB cable as a power supply for the microcontroller. I have two questions:

1. How to adjust the current flow? In the documentation I have found that typical Icc should be about 13.5 mA (p. 263). It will be enough If I put a specific resistor between VBUS and UVCC and AVCC? I do not want to burn the device, like last time.
2. If I find a correct way to power up my device via USB, then will this microcontroller be visible in Linux or Windows system? Any driver will be necessary?

[image: the device]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You don't adjust the current flow. Definitely not with a resistor. Let the MCU take whatever current it requires to operate, at the voltage it operates.
2. No it won't show up unless you write a program for the MCU which tells the PC what kind of USB device it is. If it is a device which does not need a driver then it will work, otherwise it needs a driver. It depends what kind of device you want your MCU to be.